# What test to use to compare two sets of data. One only knowing mean and quantity

Tags: hypothesis-testing, missing-data, binary-data

I have two methods that generate either a pass or a fail on input data. I want to know if statistically there is any difference between the two?

For the first method I only have the mean (0.75) and the number of data points (80k). For the second I have the complete list of data points (around 100). Each data point is either a 1 or a 0 (Pass/Fail).

Comment: In R, `qbinom(c(.025,.975), 100, .75)` returns 66 and 83. Roughly speaking this means you can reject $H_0: p=.75$ against $H_s: p < .75.$ at the 2.5% level if the number $X$ passing is below $66$ or against $H_g: p > .75$ if $X \ge 83.$ Also, reject against $H_d: p \ne .75$ at the 5% level if $X$ is beyond either of these critical values. // That is, I would use the earlier result from 80k items as the standard for $H_0.$

Comment: You have to use the Fisher exact test or chi-square test. You have enough data for that if the mean in the first group is calculated with sufficient precision.